# Springboot BindingResult does not returning any errors

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I am following [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) and I am getting not getting any validation errors but using `springboot 2.3.1.RELEASE`. I have checked various answers but they seem not to work. [Here is the repo](https://github.com/kirubidavid/LabTest)

**My bean**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class FrmSignInDto {
    
    @NotNull
    @Size
    private String txtEmail;

    public String getTxtEmail() {
        return txtEmail;
    }

    public void setTxtEmail(String txtEmail) {
        this.txtEmail = txtEmail;
    }
    
}
```

**My Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String getSignIn(Model model) {
    
    model.addAttribute("frmsignindto", new FrmSignInDto());
    
    return "fragments/auth/sign-in";
}

@PostMapping("/")
public String postSignIn(@Valid FrmSignInDto frmSignInDto, BindingResult bindingResult ) {
    
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "fragments/auth/sign-in";
    }
    System.err.println("Input "+frmSignInDto.getTxtEmail()); 

    return "redirect:/validate/";
}
```

Comment: can you share your JSON payload while making post request?

Comment: and one more thing In your controller, @valid belongs to which package? Once I was imported from the wrong package caused me the same issue

Comment: Payload txtEmail= and @Valid is from javax.validation.Valid; Here is repo https://github.com/kirubidavid/LabTest